# any way to have multiple tabs(screens) in flutter with a preview like in a browsers do for example?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

any idea where to start? what I want to archive is dynamic tabs(can open and close) with ability to see tab overview like in any browser.
[image: browser ui for example]

Comment: `url_launcher` use for new tab on web. if we want it on others design, we can use `CustomScrollView` and `sliver_tools` and `statemanagement`. i think we can make this way

Comment: do you have any image or url for reference, it's quite hard to imagine

Comment: @JimChiu added an image as a reference. nothing fantastical, but I don't need web view or address bar

Answer (score 1):

It is very easy to do with custom widget,

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

  void main() => runApp(MyApp());

  class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        home: MyHomePage(),
      );
    }
  }

  class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
    @override
    _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
  }

  class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
    List<String> data = ['Page 0', 'Page 1', 'Page 2'];
    int initPosition = 1;

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: CustomTabView(
            initPosition: initPosition,
            itemCount: data.length,
            tabBuilder: (context, index) => Tab(child: Row(children: [Text("${data[index]}"),IconButton(onPressed: (){
               setState(() {
              data.removeAt(index);
            });
            },icon: Icon(Icons.face),),],),),
            pageBuilder: (context, index) => Center(child: Text(data[index])),
            onPositionChange: (index){
              print('current position: $index');
              initPosition = index;
            },
            onScroll: (position) => print('$position'),
          ),
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              data.add('Page ${data.length}');
            });
          },
          child: Icon(Icons.add),
        ),
      );
    }
  }

  /// Implementation

  class CustomTabView extends StatefulWidget {
    final int itemCount;
    final IndexedWidgetBuilder tabBuilder;
    final IndexedWidgetBuilder pageBuilder;
    final Widget stub;
    final ValueChanged<int> onPositionChange;
    final ValueChanged<double> onScroll;
    final int initPosition;

    CustomTabView({
      @required this.itemCount,
      @required this.tabBuilder,
      @required this.pageBuilder,
      this.stub,
      this.onPositionChange,
      this.onScroll,
      this.initPosition,
    });

    @override
    _CustomTabsState createState() => _CustomTabsState();
  }

  class _CustomTabsState extends State<CustomTabView> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
    TabController controller;
    int _currentCount;
    int _currentPosition;

    @override
    void initState() {
      _currentPosition = widget.initPosition ?? 0;
      controller = TabController(
        length: widget.itemCount,
        vsync: this,
        initialIndex: _currentPosition,
      );
      controller.addListener(onPositionChange);
      controller.animation.addListener(onScroll);
      _currentCount = widget.itemCount;
      super.initState();
    }

    @override
    void didUpdateWidget(CustomTabView oldWidget) {
      if (_currentCount != widget.itemCount) {
        controller.animation.removeListener(onScroll);
        controller.removeListener(onPositionChange);
        controller.dispose();

        if (widget.initPosition != null) {
          _currentPosition = widget.initPosition;
        }

        if (_currentPosition > widget.itemCount - 1) {
            _currentPosition = widget.itemCount - 1;
            _currentPosition = _currentPosition < 0 ? 0 : 
            _currentPosition;
            if (widget.onPositionChange is ValueChanged<int>) {
               WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_){
                if(mounted) {
                  widget.onPositionChange(_currentPosition);
                }
               });
            }
         }

        _currentCount = widget.itemCount;
        setState(() {
          controller = TabController(
            length: widget.itemCount,
            vsync: this,
            initialIndex: _currentPosition,
          );
          controller.addListener(onPositionChange);
          controller.animation.addListener(onScroll);
        });
      } else if (widget.initPosition != null) {
        controller.animateTo(widget.initPosition);
      }

      super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
    }

    @override
    void dispose() {
      controller.animation.removeListener(onScroll);
      controller.removeListener(onPositionChange);
      controller.dispose();
      super.dispose();
    }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      if (widget.itemCount < 1) return widget.stub ?? Container();

      return Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: TabBar(
              isScrollable: true,
              controller: controller,
              labelColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
              unselectedLabelColor: Theme.of(context).hintColor,
              indicator: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border(
                  bottom: BorderSide(
                    color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                    width: 2,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              tabs: List.generate(
                widget.itemCount,
                    (index) => widget.tabBuilder(context, index),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: TabBarView(
              controller: controller,
              children: List.generate(
                widget.itemCount,
                    (index) => widget.pageBuilder(context, index),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      );
    }

    onPositionChange() {
      if (!controller.indexIsChanging) {
        _currentPosition = controller.index;
        if (widget.onPositionChange is ValueChanged<int>) {
          widget.onPositionChange(_currentPosition);
        }
      }
    }

    onScroll() {
      if (widget.onScroll is ValueChanged<double>) {
        widget.onScroll(controller.animation.value);
      }
    }
  }
```

i put face Icon as close ;).

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`StatefulWidget`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html) on [`TabBarView`](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/tabs).

The main idea is using `setState` when you do anything dynamically.

- Design your custom `Tab`.
- When new tab is added, store data into list. Method: `add`
- Remove specific item when close button is tapped. Method: `remove`

```dart
class BrowserLikedTabView extends StatefulWidget {
  BrowserLikedTabView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  BrowserLikedTabViewState createState() => BrowserLikedTabViewState();
}

class BrowserLikedTabViewState extends State<BrowserLikedTabView> {
  final data = <String>[];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final tabBar = TabBar(tabs: [
      for (var item in data)
        // pass method `remove` to the tab
        Tab(child: BrowserLikedTab(item: item, onPressed: remove))
    ]);

    final tabView = TabBarView(children:[ for (var item in data)
      Text(item)
    ]);

    return Column(children: <Widget>[
      tabBar,
      Expanded(child: tabView),
    ]);
  }

  void add(String value) {
    // notice the `setState` method
    setState(() => data.add(value));
  }

  void remove(String value) {
    /// In practice, you should have the index of `item`.
    /// Use `removeAt` for better performance,
    /// since `removeWhere` will loop all the element in array.
    setState(() => data.removeWhere((e) => e == value));
  }
}
```

The tab design is something likes:

```dart
class BrowserLikedTab extends StatelessWidget {
  final String item;

  final void Function(String) onPressed;

  const BrowserLikedTab({this.item, this.onPressed});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    /// You may need MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween to
    /// move your icon in correct place.
    /// Try the options to fit your design.
    return Row(children: [
      IconButton(
        onPressed: () => onPressed(item),
        icon: Icon(Icons.cancel),
      ),
      // You may need truncate overflow for text.
      Text(item),
    ]);
  }
}
```

> The pattern I used for loop is recommended in [Dart document](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/usage#collections).

> [`TabBar`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TabBar-class.html) property `isScrollable` is a property you might want to look for if you have dynamic tabs.

Now you can call the `add` outside the `TabBarView`.

```
class AddButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final tabBarView = GlobalKey<BrowserLikedTabViewState>();

  AddButton({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(children:[
        TextButton(
          onPressed: () => tabBarView.currentState?.add('new item'),
          child: Text('Add now'),
        ),
        Expanded(child: BrowserLikedTabView(key: tabBarView)),
      ]),
    );
  }
}
```